# How to access to the Interactive Console from a deployed application in Google App Engine Standard?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have used the `dev_appserver.py app.yaml --enable_console` and I was able to make use of the Interactive Console by going to the url localhost:8000 or Web Preview and port 8000 using the Cloud Shell option.

But when I deployed the application into GAE Standard using the same app.yaml as in development:

```
runtime: python39

handlers:

 - url: /app
   script: main.py
 
- url: /admin/.*
   script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
   login: admin
```

I can not access neither the console or the admin by using the the link provided in the Cloud Shell as: `gcloud app browse` and add it the `/admin/` and other variations to the url.

Example:

```
  <project-name>.appspot.com/admin
  <project-name>.appspot.com/admin/
  <project-name>.appspot.com/admin/console
```

I am greeted with a Not Found page. I have also tried to use Postman and obtianed the same result.

**How do I properly access the Interactive Console of a deployed application in Google App Engine?**

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2):

What is it that you are trying use the interactive console to do?

If youre just trying to interact with Google Datastore via `ndb` you just need to open a python shell in your terminal at your project root and initialize `ndb` with your project id:

```
$ python
>>> from google.cloud import ndb
>>> ndb_client = ndb.Client(project='my-project-id')
>>> ndb_context = ndb_client.context()
>>> ndb_context.__enter__()
>>> # start interacting with your datastore
```

If you get a permissions error, then I think that means that the google service account specified in your env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` doesnt have access to that project.

The same goes for other actions like enqueuing cloud tasks via the python library `google-cloud-tasks`

Comment: My intention is to be able to access the same tools as in development with dev_appserver.py

Comment: Which tools? What specifically are you trying to do? `localhost:8000` is just a simple version of GCP's actual web console here console.cloud.google.com. The only thing it lacks is the `Interactive Console`, but the option I listed should do almost anything you would do in there. Also, does `google.appengine.ext.admin.application` in your app.yaml actually work? Where did you copy that from? All libraries under `google.appengine.*` were the python2 libraries and we're told to not use them in python3: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.admin

Comment: @alex - You're referring to the Bundled APIs and these have been made available in Python 3. See documentation  - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access

Comment: oh my god, this stuff would've made my py2 -> py3 migration so much easier. It looks like this just came out last fall. Do these things get announced anywhere?

Comment: @Alex : Yes, on their blog - https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/new-java-ruby-python-php-runtimes. However, it's easy to miss since their blog has a lot of information. They also announce it on the Google App Engine discussion group - https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine. Final option is to follow our account on Twitter (we track information about GAE and retweet it)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't know if what you're doing is possible but the script you have supplied doesn't seem to exist. [This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/services/bundled/google/appengine/ext) is a link to the `google.appengine.ext` module and it doesn't have the module you're referring to.
2. Also not sure why you need the interactive console when you're on production given that you have `console.cloud.google.com` which gives you access to what the interactive console gives you. My understanding is that interactive console is for dev server only and is basically a simulation of what you get from `console.cloud.google.com`

Comment: When running this command dev_appserver.py app.yaml --enable_console, you are able to access to the 'google.appengine.ext.admin.application', in this webserver, there is an option named 'Interactive Console'. My idea is to be able to access it, the same way as I am doing in development.

Comment: I'm saying the ```google.appengine.ext.admin``` module isn't supported for Python3 (see the link in my answer). That module only exists for Python2 - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.admin